# Is this safe to download and use Gutenprint driver for Mac from their site?

Tags: software

Good day everyone!

I am in a bit of a conundrum.

On one hand, I heard following site is good to download Gutenprint software:

gimp-print.sourceforge.net/p_Download.php

On other hand, I also heard sourceforge site is bundled with malicious software.

So, is that place safe? Their download links are also in sourceforge.net.

Is Gutenprint safe to use and is it safe to use the linked site?

Comment: This is on topic since it's about using third party software on a Mac. Also - objective information on how to verify downloads is not only on-topic but extremely welcome. This is +1 in my eyes and possibly bounty worthy if it doesn't attract any answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer very simply, if you want to know if something is safe or not, go on [Virus Total](http://virustotal.com) and copy paste the link of the download file. But, if you download a software from their official website and you trust this company, just download it, it should be fine